# R user defined function in dplyr summarise

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to use a user-defined function within `dplyr` `summarise`.
The dataset I am working on can be [downloaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9791jz40xjoqeo/raw_data.csv?dl=0) and prepped for use using the following code:

```
raw_data <- read.csv("Output/FluxN2O.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test_data <- raw_data %>% mutate(Chamber = as.factor(Chamber), Treatment = as.factor(Treatment. Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
```

Here is the `head()`

```
> head(test_data)
             Time Chamber_closed         Slope R_Squared Chamber Treatment   Flux_N2O Time_relative Time_cumulative
1 2016-05-03 00:08:21          10.23  8.873843e-07 0.6941540      10        AN  0.7567335           0.0             0.0
2 2016-05-03 06:10:21          12.24 -5.540907e-06 0.7728001      12         U -4.7251117         362.0           362.0
3 2016-05-03 06:42:21          10.24 -5.260463e-06 0.9583473      10        AN -4.4859581          32.0           394.0
4 2016-05-03 07:12:21           9.23 -5.320429e-06 0.7602987       9        IU -4.5370951          30.0           424.0
5 2016-05-03 07:42:21           7.23  3.135043e-06 0.7012436       7         U  2.6734669          30.0           454.0
6 2016-05-03 20:10:15           5.24  5.215290e-06 0.7508935       5        AN  4.4474364         747.9          1201.9
```

For each level of the factor `Chamber`, I want to calculate the area under the curve when x = `Time_cumulative` and y = `Flux_n2O`.

I can do this using the following function passed to a `by` call:

```
cum_ems_func <- function(x) {last(cumtrapz(x$Time_cumulative, x$Flux_N2O))}
by(test_data, test_data$Chamber, cum_ems_func)
```

However, I would prefer to use `dpylr` as there is further data processing to be done which will be easiest using the `summarise` output.

When I try to use the `dplyr` approach

```
test_data %>% 
group_by(Chamber) %>% 
summarise(cumulative_emmission = last(cumtrapz(Time_cumulative, Flux_N2O)))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported vector type language
```

I have also tried using the user-defined function `cums_ems_func` within the summarise call with the resulting error:

```
test_data %>% 
group_by(Chamber) %>% 
summarise(cumulative_emmission = cum_ems_func())
Error: argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this please?

Comment: Please add `dput(head(test_data))` to your question

Comment: The last approach needs you to pass the function some data, but the way you've defined it, it will need the whole group of the data.frame, which is represented by `.`. You could redefine the function to take two variables, if you like, so you could just pass column names. The previous version is more common, and should work as far as I can tell. What's the `cumtrapz` function, and what are its parameters?

Comment: @alistaire `cumtrapz` is a function for calculating the area under a curve by trapezoidal integration. It is part of the "pracma" package. I have tried using `.` but it gave me the same value for each level of the `Chamber` factor. I will have a go at changing the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly then one of the following should do the job

```
library(pracma); library(dplyr)


test_data <- test_data %>% group_by(Chamber) %>% 
             mutate(emission=max(cumtrapz(Time_cumulative, Flux_N2O))) %>% ungroup

### or 

test_data <- test_data %>% group_by(Chamber) %>% 
             mutate(cumulative_emission=cumtrapz(Time_cumulative, Flux_N2O)) %>% ungroup
```